# Video texture not playing in viewport or during render: how to fix?

Tags: rendering, animation, video

Relatively new user here with what I hope to be a simple question.

Following the method of [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=WqDz0jZlmiQ), I applied a .MOV file as a textured material to one face of a cube. When I execute a playback of the scene, the video doesn’t play in the 3D Viewport. And whenever I render the scene the texture appears still—I don’t see the frames pass during the render process.

Here’s a photo of my screen to help illustrate what I’m describing, and here's a [link to the Blender file](https://pasteall.org/blend/e492aa4c5c1b4d46876b8f4f8d8482f1).

[image: Screenshot of workspace]

In case it matters, here are my system specs:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Intel i3-10100
- Nvidia GTX 1650
- 16GB RAM

Comment: pls upload your file:https://pasteall.org/blend/, in my case,it's ok

Comment: Hi! It appears you meant to leave a link for a video but it hasn't appeared properly in your question. It's okay to just paste a link as text. It seems that your question is answerable without said link but just a heads up :)

Comment: Oops! Fixed the hyperlink and uploaded the Blender file

Comment: maybe try with other video, not a mov or a different codec

Comment: Tried with an MP4 and saw improved results. But, after 100 frames, the rendered video starts to look pretty weird (the output has frames that I can only describe as "jumpy," i.e. the output video seems to skip forwards and backwards randomly).

Comment: For reference, here's a [125-frame rendering](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4h2jsrbngpwmx4p/0001-0125.avi?dl=0). The jittering I described happens briefly at the end. If I were to render the same scene for 200 frames, you would continue to see that defect for 101-200 frames.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up converting the .mp4 into an image sequence and re-configuring the texture node to recognize it as such (instead of a movie). I used the ffmpeg utility to accomplish this, as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088222/ffmpeg-convert-video-to-images). Not an ideal workaround but it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem placing an MP4 file as an image texture (Movie). I couldn't see the movie in the viewport or when rendering. But it was displayed in the "Image Editor Tab".

I deleted the "Principal BSDF" and then added a new "Principal BSDF". After reconnecting the nodes (*Color > Emission*), it finally worked.

I could not find the error in the previous BSDF.

Settings now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also tried converting to an image sequence (make sure each image ends in the format -0001, -0002) and it also fixed this problem. The other solutions didn't end up working. What's weird is that I have 8 of these textures and only the last 4 of them in my project didn't work.

EDIT: Spoke a bit too soon, there's still odd issues with this. Checking *Cyclic* did get it working again, which seems to indicate this might be because of a mismatch between frame number / start frame / offset making the image texture only display the first or last frame and just sitting there. Not sure yet, I'm definitely a beginner here!